# AWS c1.medium instance store - locked out by saving authorized_keys on full disk

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-instance-store

When adding a public key to /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys, it appears the file was wiped empty because the disk was full.

Unfortunately the person I talked through this process logged out and we don't have any password to access this root volume.

Is there any way to recover from this situation?

I have checked adding user data on reboot, but this only seems to be available when the server is stopped. We obviosuly also can't mount the root disk anywhere else without loosing it.

Comment: Why can you not mount the disk anywhere else? A standard recovery method is to mount on another EC2 instance.

Comment: Instance store is part of the instance, not separate like ebs volumes.  You can't detach the instance store, and it isn't accessible from another instance.  Even if the instance is stopped, the instance store is deleted:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: This is when you contact Amazon. That’s what they are there for.

Comment: @Appleoddity Amazon's gonna say "shouldn't have done that". Their support won't (and can't, to my knowledge) fix this sort of thing. Creating an AMI of the instance *might* work, but I honestly haven't done that with an instance-store instance in years.